# very low Be4 chamber pressure

Tags: rockets

How does Blue Horizons be4 manage to achieve such low chamber pressure compared to the SpaceX raptor engine or the shuttle main engines and yet still deliver more thrust given it does not appear to be significantly bigger ?

Comment: You should compare not only chamber pressure but also nozzle diameter (at the narrow point), exhaust velocity and propellant mass flow.

Comment: You might note that chamber pressure does not appear in the thrust equation. https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rockth.html

Answer (score 3):

As Organic Marble suggests the thrust equation

```
F = dm/dt * v_e + (p_e - p_a) * A_e
```

somewhat hides the chamber pressure; it is only relevant for `v_e`. 
*(In this formular a is for ambient, e = nozzle exit)*

Being heat engines rocket engine are limited by Carnot's theorem which basically says that the maximum efficiency (how much of the energy stored in the fuel can actually be used) is:

```
eta = 1 - T_min / T_max
```

In the case of a rocket engine the `T_max` is always the chamber temperature and `T_min` is the temperature of the exhaust gas. The chamber temperature is relatively fixed by the flame temperature of our fuel and only slightly increases with the chamber pressure (but that additional energy is gained from the pumps so this is more or less a zero sum game).

What we can do is reduce T_min namely the exhaust temperature. In an optimal [isentropic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process):

```
T_min / T_max = (p_min / p_max)^((kappa - 1) / kappa)
```

where kappa is the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio).

That means we can increase our efficiency if we reduce `p_min / p_max`. Sadly we can't reduce `p_min = p_e` below the ambient pressure `p_a` simply using a bigger nozzle because we would face flow seperation and a performance degradation as seen in the second part of the thrust equation `(p_e - p_a) * A_e`. The optimal exhaust pressure is exactly equal to the ambient pressure.

In order to achieve small ratios we can therefore do only one thing in high ambient pressures: increase the chamber pressure. But working out the numbers there isn't that much gain (asuming `p_a = 0.5 bar` which is true after the first 5km, `kappa ~ 1.4`):

```
eta_merlin = 1 - (0.05 MPa / 9.72 MPa)^((1.4 - 1) / 1.4) = 0.7781
eta_be4    = 1 - (0.05 MPa / 13.4 MPa)^((1.4 - 1) / 1.4) = 0.7976
eta_raptor = 1 - (0.05 MPa / 25.0 MPa)^((1.4 - 1) / 1.4) = 0.8306
```

which means Raptor might perform up to *~4% better* in the atmosphere but higher chamber pressure adds complexity and results in higher dry mass which reduces payload.

In the end the difference is not as big as one might expect.

---

The Wikipedia article on [isentropic nozzle flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_nozzle_flow) is a good read if you want more details.

Comment: But what about the combustion chamber volume? Is it possible to reduce the necessary chamber volume by increasing chamber pressure?